# Series expansion of $\frac{e^z}{z}$ around $z=-1$ in region $|z+1|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Basically, I approached this problem using the basic Taylor Series Expansion formula:
$$f(z)=f(z_0) + \frac{f'(z_0)}{1!}(z-z_0)+\frac{f''(z_0)}{2!}(z-z_0)^2+\cdots$$

From there, I got stuck with
$$f(z)=-\frac{1}{e}-\frac{2}{e}(z+1)-\frac{5}{2!e}(z+1)^2-\frac{16}{3!e}(z+1)^3-\frac{65}{4!e}(z+1)^4-\cdots$$

I would like to represent this as a sum $\sum$ but don't know what to do next.

Alternatively, I found the Taylor Series Expansion for $e^z$ and simply wrote
$$f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z+1)^j}{zej!}$$

Comment: You may prove by mathematical induction that the coefficient for the $n$-th power is $-e^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$. Actually, it is easier to obtain the series expansion of $f(z)=-e^{-1}e^w(1-w)^{-1}$ (where $w=z+1$) 
by using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of $e^w=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{w^k}{k!}$ and $(1-w)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^k$.

Comment: Since I have not covered Cauchy products, how would I go by using this method?

Comment: You may also use [Leibniz’ rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for higher derivatives of product of functions to obtain the result.